# Multiple NavBars on Shiny Dashboard-- remove weird spacing

Tags: html, css, r, user-interface, shiny

I am using multiple navbars on my shiny dashboard page because I plan to create a conditional filter based on which tab is selected. Can the space between the two nav bars be removed?

Also, can the space reserved for the title be removed? I've seen some similar questions on here but I am pretty bad with CSS, so if someone could show me exactly where I can edit my code, that would be awesome.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 325,
               uiOutput("filter")),
  dashboardBody( 
    navbarPage(header="",title=NULL,id="trythis" ,
         tabPanel("BigTab1",
                  navbarPage(title = NULL,id="firstbar",  
                  tabPanel("SubTab1",
                             dataTableOutput("table1")),
                  tabPanel("SubTab2"))),
        tabPanel("BigTab2",
                 navbarPage(title=NULL,id="secondbar",
                   tabPanel("SubTab3",
                            dataTableOutput("table2")),
                   tabPanel("SubTab4")))
        )
)
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$table1<-renderDataTable({
    data<-filter(mtcars,cyl %in% input$test)
    data.table(data[,1:2])
  },options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, -1), pageLength = 5))

  output$table2<-renderDataTable({
    data<-filter(mtcars,cyl %in% input$test)
    data.table(data[,1:2])
  },options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 10, -1), pageLength = 5))

  output$filter<-renderUI({
    if(input$trythis=="BigTab1"){
    selectInput("test","Test",choices =    c("4","6","8"),selected=c("4","6"),multiple = TRUE)
    }else{
      selectInput("test","Test",choices = c("4","6","8"),multiple = FALSE)

    }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to remove the red, more worried about the space between the bars than the others, but the title space on the navbar is also pretty bad when you make the window smaller. Thanks in advance for any help!

[image]

Comment: Including the generated HTML and the CSS that is used would be helpful to answer your question.

Comment: According to this doc https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/appearance.html#css you can do a custom css file to override the defaults styles

Comment: Oh yeah, i know that is an option but I'm not sure what I would put in there/ how I would reference the CSS within my R code. Any ideas?

Comment: in css you can use `flex` or `display:table` to get it in single row.

Comment: @SarahGC I can write what css you need, I'll post it as response if you still need help?

Comment: but as John says, put the generated HTML in your response to see what is need to be modified

Comment: I don't know how to do that. can i run it in R so that it'll show the html?

Comment: Yeah you can do that, and in your browser you can do a mouse right click the tabs element for example and select the `inspect` option the browser will show the HTML, share and screenshot of that or paste the HTM